# MVC beginner - Advice on how to persist a user selection for use throughout the site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an application which is centered around data per 'team'.  A user belongs to a team and if they log in they only see that team's data.

However,  I now have super users who essentially belong to more than one team.  These users should be able to log in to the system and then immediately choose which team they are interested in.  From then on they will essentially view/create data against that selected team. They should also have the option to go and change what team they are viewing at any time.

I've established that the user would like to be able to have multiple tabs open and be viewing a different team in each tab.

I'm struggling to work out the best way to accomplish this with .NET MVC while keeping it as stateless and testable as possible.

I've been reading up on the different ways to persist data - session state and cookies seem to get a bad rep in MVC.  TempData, ViewBag seem to focus on just persisting data for one request.

I wouldn't have thought that this is an uncommon requirement in an application - are there known patterns for dealing with this in MVC which I have missed?

So far I'm trying to create a partial view which I can show on each page to let the user see what team they are viewing the site as, and change it from there.

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to let your superuser view multiple teams data then you'll want to pass the team information in on the request, on the query string or as something that looks like a restful url:

```
/blueteam/members
```

In fact it would be extra work to track this in a stateful manner as you'd have track user, team, and ui element when a superuser can view multiple team data at once.

I'd say passing the information in on every request is a pretty standard approach to your situation.

The tricky part of the stateless approach is decorating all your internal application links with the team information without too much extra work. Relative links can be your friends here. So a link to the bug page for a team might be to simply "bugs", picking up the team name higher in the uri path. If you are creating something that looks like a one page application it's easy enough to store the team info on the client.

If you don't want team members to see data for other team members, you can set up guard functions that check for team membership for certain classes of users before rendering a view.

Comment: In short, you simply provide the slugs/ids for the objects you need to work with in the URL, then use those values to lookup the information from the database. You don't need to actually persist the entire objects themselves between requests.